# JWT Middleware in express not working after import

Tags: node.js, express, import, export, middleware

This is my index.js

```
import express from "express";
import router from "./routes/routes.js";
import connectDB from "./db.js";

const app = express();

connectDB();

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/", router);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("server is running on port 3000"));
```

This is my jwt file which uses a middleware function on posts request

```
import express from "express";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import authenticateToken from "./middlewares/authenticateToken.js";

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Node and JWT"));

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    id: 1,
    username: "JhonDoe",
    email: "Jhon@gmail.com",
  };

  const token = jwt.sign(user, "secret", { expiresIn: "1day" });
  res.json({ token });
});

app.post("/posts", authenticateToken, (req, res) => {
  const user = req.user;
  res.json(user);
});

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("server is running on port 4000"));
```

And this is the middleware

```
export default function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  console.log(token);
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: "No token, authorization denied" });
  }

  try {
    const user = jwt.verify(token, "secret");
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(token);
    res.status(403).json({ msg: "Token is not valid" });
  }
}
```

But when I import it, it doesn't work correctly if I show the token in the console it shows it correctly but it returns the error "token is not valid" but if I use it below the post request in the same jwt.js file it works perfectly it show me the payload, why doesn't it work when I import it?, thanks.

Comment: Did you do basic debugging and trace through `authenticateToken()` and see exactly what it sees and does either by  stepping through in the debugger or by inserting various `console.log()` statements?  Does it even get called when you are importing it?

Comment: Also, what is `console.log(first);` in `authenticateToken()`?  That seems like it would cause an immediate error as there is no `first` variable shown.

Comment: hahahaha that console.log(first) was a copy paste error here, I already modified it. But no, I already solved it, I was using the JWT library asynchronously when I'm not using asynchrony, I had to verify the token synchronously. more info here https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#readme

Answer (score 0):

Solution

**Instead of**

```
export default function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: "No token, authorization denied" });
  }

  try {
    const user = jwt.verify(token, "secret");
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(403).json({ msg: "Token is not valid" });
  }
}
```

**this**

```
export default function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: "No token, authorization denied" });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, "secret", (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.status(403).json({ msg: "Token is not valid" });
    req.user = user;

    next();
  });
}
```

Documentation https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#readme

Comment: Why the extra comma in the arguments here: `jwt.verify(token, "secret" , );`?  Is that part of your solution?  If so, doesn't make sense to me.  Plus, your whole solution seems unclear.  `jwt.verify()` works synchronous if you don't pass it a callback as a third argument.  So, the code in your question was already calling it synchronously.

Comment: This doesn't look correct.  The synchronous form of `jwt.verify()` will throw if it isn't valid.  From the `jwt.verify()` [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback).  ***(Synchronous) If a callback is not supplied, function acts synchronously. Returns the payload decoded if the signature is valid and optional expiration, audience, or issuer are valid. If not, it will throw the error.***  So, you still need the `try/catch` which you have apparently removed.

Comment: I implemented the way that the documentation specifies and with that it is already working for me. By the way, I already modified the third comma, I forgot to enter the callback. Thanks for making me notice.

Comment: OK, so NOW you're actually using the callback interface?  That wasn't in the first version of this answer.  How confusing.  OK, I'll leave now.  This statement at the start of your answer " the token had to be verified synchronously" is wrong.  Your new solution with the callback is working ***asynchronously***.  Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the problem happens when doing the import but if I directly use the middleware below the request in the same file, the try catch works without problem. I'll remove the sentence from my solution because yes, now I'm applying the callback which also makes the code work. Thanks for your time dude.